# Python subprocess different approaches

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following structure

```
- folder1
-- script1.py
- folder2
-- script2_1.py
-- script2_2.py
- folder2
-- script3.py
```

script2_1.py has the following line in it

```
os.system("python3 script2_2.py "+str(id))
```

If I SSH into the instance, cd to folder2 and then run script2_1.py

```
python3 script2_1.py
```

it works fine and script2_2.py is called as expected.

---

Now in script1.py I want to call both script2_2.py and script3.py. I've tested different approaches but no success yet.

**Approach 1**:

```
id = str(id)
subprocess.check_call(["/folder2", "script2_2.py "+id])
subprocess.check_call(["/folder3", "script3.py "+id])
```

which gives

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/folder2'

**Approach 2:**

```
id = str(id)
commands = '''
cd /folder2/ 
python3 script2_2.py {} 
cd /folder3/ 
python3 script3.py {} 
'''.format(id, id)
p = subprocess.Popen("/bin/sh", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate(commands.encode('utf-8'))
```

which gives

> /bin/sh: python3: not found

**Approach 3:**

```
id = str(id)
subprocess.call(['cd /folder2/','python3 script2_2.py {}'.format(id)])
subprocess.call(['cd /folder3/','python3 script3.py {}'.format(id)])
```

which gives

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cd /folder2/': 'cd /folder2/'

**Approach 4**:

In this one I've tested args with both string and list, specifying the full path to the .py file, with and without shell=True, without sys.path and with full path in subprocess.call, ...

```
id = str(id)
#import sys
#sys.path.insert(1, '/folder2/')
subprocess.call(['/usr/local/bin/python3','/folder2/script2_2.py {}'.format(id)])
#sys.path.insert(1, '/folder3/')
subprocess.call(['/usr/local/bin/python3','/folder3/script3.py {}'.format(id)])
```

which gives

> /usr/local/bin/python3: can't open file '/folder2/script2_2.py 80': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>
> /usr/local/bin/python3: can't open file '/folder3/script3.py 80': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I manage to solve it by using and adaptation of **Approach 2** with the full path to python3.

```
id = str(id)
commands = '''
cd /folder2/ 
/usr/local/bin/python3 script2_2.py {} 
cd /folder3/ 
/usr/local/bin/python3 script3.py {} 
'''.format(id, id)
p = subprocess.Popen("/bin/sh", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate(commands.encode('utf-8'))
```

To know which one is I SSH into the instance and ran

```
which python3
```

which returned

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```